# Easier way than using QuantLib to compute the price and Greeks of a vanilla European option?

Tags: options, programming, quantlib

I'm using the following to compute the price and Greeks a vanilla European option:

```
import QuantLib as ql

maturity_date = ql.Date(15, 1, 2016)
spot_price = 127.62
strike_price = 130
volatility = 0.20
dividend_rate =  0.0163
option_type = ql.Option.Call
        
risk_free_rate = 0.001
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
        
calculation_date = ql.Date(8, 5, 2015)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date

payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(option_type, strike_price)
exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(maturity_date)
european_option = ql.VanillaOption(payoff, exercise)

spot_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(
            ql.SimpleQuote(spot_price)
        )
flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, 
                           risk_free_rate, 
                           day_count)
        )
dividend_yield = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, 
                           dividend_rate, 
                           day_count)
        )
flat_vol_ts = ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(
            ql.BlackConstantVol(calculation_date, 
                                calendar, 
                                volatility, 
                                day_count)
        )
bsm_process = ql.BlackScholesMertonProcess(spot_handle, 
                                                   dividend_yield, 
                                                   flat_ts, 
                                                   flat_vol_ts)

european_option.setPricingEngine(ql.AnalyticEuropeanEngine(bsm_process))

# price
bs_price = european_option.NPV()

price
6.749271812460607

# Greek sensitivities
delta = european_option.delta()
gamma = european_option.gamma()
vega = european_option.vega()
theta = european_option.theta()

delta
0.4582969846433817

gamma
0.018522331553816086

vega
41.655351781911605

theta
-5.131800499907545
```

This is a ***lengthy*** amount of code to price a vanilla option.  Is there a more straightforward way?

Yes, I'm well aware that QuantLib is an extremely powerful engine and not necessarily built for simplicity, as mentioned very eloquently by @SmallChess in [Why does it take so many lines of code to price even the simplest of options with QuantLib](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21046/why-does-it-take-so-many-lines-of-code-to-price-even-the-simplest-of-options-wit).

Are there any wrapper functions that I might be able to use to simplify things?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think of QuantLib as a set of very powerfull tools/parts which you can use to build your own pricers.

If you are going to price a single option, yes it takes a bit of boilerplate code to get the result.

But you can always reuse this code for different inputs, specially if you want to do sensitivity analysis. I think the way QuantLib stores inputs with quotes, enabling all consequent recomputation makes up for the initial boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply code the formulas yourself, but this would not reduce the amount of code. I would say using quantlib is already very compact.